# how to find Page id inwordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, php4

i need to get page ID in wordpress throught php?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [the_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for a Theme, it's as simple as [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID).

Answer (score 0):

There is a global variable "`$post`" which contains the related information of the current post / page, and is actually an object. You can access information just as you access variables from an object. Remember to keep it in the while loop.

For example, confider the following:-

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();
        global $post;
        $idPagePost = $post->ID;
    endwhile;
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now the variable "$idPagePost" will contain the ID of the current page / post.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wp_query;
$id = $wp_query->post->ID;
// OR:
$id = $wp_query->queried_object_id;
```

This will work anywhere in your themes or plugins, as long as it happens after WordPress is loaded.

Comment: I should add that both of these will work anywhere on singular pages (single blog, static page, etc.), but you should use the first for multi-view pages inside the loop. The second will only work on singular pages, while the first will only give you the first returned post on multi-post views, unless you're using it in the loop.